# There are several ways optimize portfolio, why use Black Litterman rather than Mean variance

Tags: portfolio, optimization

I know there are two ways to optimize portfolio. What are the limitations and advantages by using Black Litterman over Mean variance.

Comment: There are no advantages. It's an old outdated model that probably no one uses in industry. Giving an investor the ability to include their own views on what they think assets will do doesn't make a model any better. It could make it much worse

Comment: This question is answered by the Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Litterman_model under 'Background'. BL provides a more complicated but better way to specify Expected Returns. Errors in expected returns are a major problem for practical application of MVO. The careful, 2 step process in BL can help come up with better solution.

Comment: If someone is using BL, they are using it as a complement to MVO (or any other portfolio optimization method), not instead of

Comment: @develarist Thanks very much for you help, could you please shed me some light about what model is popular if not the most in industry ?

Comment: Some good leads here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/49869/what-does-the-concept-standard-markowitz-approach-include/49871#49871